# Identify unique trips for each user where walking is followed by trip start

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands, sorting

I have a table `trips` with the following information

| Row | User | Timestamp | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:03 | Walking |
| 2 | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:02 | Walking |
| 3 | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:01 | Start |
| 4 | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:03 | Walking |
| 5 | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:02 | Walking |
| 6 | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:01 | Start |
| 7 | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:03 | Walking |
| 8 | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:02 | Walking |
| 9 | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:01 | Start |
| 10 | 2 | 27/06/2022 16:55:03 | Walking |
| 11 | 2 | 27/06/2022 16:55:02 | Walking |
| 12 | 2 | 27/06/2022 16:55:01 | Start |

I would like to add a column that groups the users by `User`, sorts by `Timestamp` descending, and then identifies different trips wherever 'Start' is followed by 'Walking'. The identified trips should then be allocated a trip number in `Trip nr`.

| Row | User | Timestamp | Event | Trip Nr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:03 | Walking | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:02 | Walking | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:01 | Start | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:03 | Walking | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:02 | Walking | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:01 | Start | 3 |
| 7 | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:03 | Walking | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:02 | Walking | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:01 | Start | 2 |
| 10 | 2 | 27/06/2022 16:55:03 | Walking | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | 27/06/2022 16:55:02 | Walking | 1 |
| 12 | 2 | 27/06/2022 16:55:01 | Start | 1 |

How can I achieve this optimally?

Comment: Please provide insert scripts for the person helping you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a SQL pattern called *gaps and islands.* The goal is to associate a unique grouping ID with each "island", then you can use `GROUP BY` to separate them out.

The first step is to determine where a *gap* is between each *island,* in a SQL sense. For your case, you already flag each new island by calling it `Start`. The next step is to assign a unique ID to each block headed by a `Start`. To create this ID we  use a rolling sum over a column that is 1 when the row is a `Start` and 0 otherwise. It turns out that the rolling sum column is identical to your `Trip Nr` column. We now have each trip uniquely identified.

[Demonstration fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6SwPTm0A).

The final query is:

```
 SELECT s.user_id AS "User",
    s.ts AS "Timestamp",
    s.event AS "Event",
    s.trip_nr AS "Trip Nr"
   FROM ( SELECT t.user_id,
            t.ts,
            t.event,
            sum(t.start_indicator) OVER (ORDER BY t.user_id, t.ts) AS trip_nr
           FROM ( SELECT trips.user_id,
                    trips.ts,
                    trips.event,
                        CASE
                            WHEN trips.event = 'Start'::text THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS start_indicator
                   FROM trips) t) s
  ORDER BY s.user_id ASC, s.ts DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But the query doesn't work if there are overlapping or similar timestamps between users.

Comment: Oops, probably need to add user_id to the window function sort. I’ll look at it tonight.

Comment: Updated query, added `user_id` to window function sort term. It means that trip numbers become a bit more arbitrary, but that's mostly unavoidable in the face of overlapping times for different user IDs. You can always add a new outer query to rearrange them as needed.